# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not timing out for iPhone5

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code in a location service:

```
.factory('Location', function($q, $ionicLoading) {
        return {
            getCurrentPosition: function() {
                var deferred  = $q.defer();
                $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Getting Location...'});
                navigator.geolocation
                    .getCurrentPosition(
                    function (data) {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        var data = 'Error getting current position.';
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        deferred.reject(data);
                    },
                    {timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy:false});
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
```

I use PhoneGap Build to build the project and then install on my iPhone5.

All works fine till I turn off Location services:

[image]

I expect the timeout to occur after 5 seconds and the error to display.  However, my app just hangs.  Any ideas timeout is not triggered?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, disabling location services should trigger your error/failure callback. Is your `$ionicLoading` hiding? Is it successfully hiding on the success callback? I'd suggested throwing a  `console.log()` in your error callback and setting up weinre debugging just to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax issue.

My simplified code above did not include this bad syntax:

```
var data = {};
switch(error.code) {
//...error message code here
}
data.push({errorCode: error.code,
           errorMessage: errorMessage});
```

which I fixed by changing to this:

```
switch(error.code) {
//...error message code here
}
var data = {errorCode: error.code,
                errorMessage: errorMessage};
```